# How to load url images in PageViewController using SDWebImage in Ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

Hi i am very new for ios and in my project i am using `PageViewController` 
for displaying and swiping the images,Ok that's fine

But here i am loading images on my `pageViewcontroller` from services(i mean url images i am loading)

For this i am using `SDWebImage` library for loading images,But here i have underlined clearly where i am getting errors below in my RootViewController.m  please help me how can i load images in `PageViewController` using `SDWebImage` library and what is the wrong in that line please help me

### my code:-

### PageContentViewController.h

```
@interface PageContentViewController: UIViewController

@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView * ivScreenImage;


@property NSUInteger pageIndex;
@property NSString *imgFile;
@property NSString *txtTitle;

@end
```

### PageContentViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.ivScreenImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.imgFile];

}
```

### RootViewController.h

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

@interface RootViewController : UIViewController
<UIPageViewControllerDataSource>

@property (nonatomic,strong) UIPageViewController *PageViewController;

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *arrPageImages;

- (PageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;

@end
```

### RootViewController.m

```
        - (void)viewDidLoad{

        [super viewDidLoad];

        arrPageImages =@[@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image1.jpg",@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image2.jpg",@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image3.jpg"];

        }



        - (PageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index{

        if (([self.arrPageTitles count] == 0) || (index >= [self.arrPageTitles count])) {
        return nil;
        }

        // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
        PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];

        pageContentViewController.imgFile setImageWithURL:[[[NSURL URLWithString:[self.arrPageImages[index]
                           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;

        return pageContentViewController;
        }
```

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: [ pageContentViewController.imgFile setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.arrPageImages[index]]                                                                               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];  try this

Comment: hi i have already underline that code in my RootViewController.m file i.e  imgFile do not having property "setImageWithURL"

Comment: [[[NSURL URLWithString:[self.arrPageImages[index] this statement is wrong to many open brackets

Comment: this statement should work `[pageContentViewController.imgFile setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.arrPageImages[index]]                                                                               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];`  try this

Comment: hello ismail in that line it's showing error like imgFile  does not having setImageWithURL property

Comment: imgFile, is it `UIImageView`? or some other class. it must be `UIImageView`

Comment: it's not UIImageView it is NSString

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98972/discussion-between-abhiram-and-ismail).

Answer (score 2):

SDWebImage method for setting image for `UIImageView` is

```
sd_setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder
```

also imgFile variable should be `UIImageView`.